# Start and destroy system process in Elixir

Tags: system, elixir

I want to start and destroy a system process.

I know that to start a process, I can use `System.cmd "my_app", []`, but it doesn't return a pid for the application and I cannot destroy (kill) it.

Does Elixir have any method for managing child processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `System.cmd`, you can use:

```
port = Port.open(
    {:spawn_executable "my_app"},
    [
        {:args, args},
        :stream,
        :binary,
        :exit_status,
        :hide,
        :use_stdio,
        :stderr_to_stdout
    ]
)
```

You can then get the PID of the process by doing `{:os_pid, pid} = Port.info(port, :os_pid)` and you can kill the process using `System.cmd("kill #{pid}")`.

Elixir Port: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Port.html

Erlang Ports and Port Drivers: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/ports.html

Comment: `System.cmd/1` has been replaced with `System.cmd/2` for security reasons. This is the correct way to invoke `kill` now: `System.cmd("kill", ["#{pid}"])`

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Porcelain](https://github.com/alco/porcelain) which is what most people use in the Elixir community